# Django DeserializedObject update

Tags: python, django, serialization

I have a dynamically loaded object from a json file.

As per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/serialization/#deserializing-data), I can save the object in this way:

```py
for deserialized_object in serializers.deserialize("json", data):
    if object_should_be_saved(deserialized_object):
        deserialized_object.save()
```

However, if the object already exists in the datadatabase, I quite rightly get the `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint` .

I can't see anything in the docs that would allow to do a `deserialized_object.update()` instead of a `deserialized_object.save()`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) and [`model_to_dict`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/models.py#L71):

```py
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

for deserialized_object in serializers.deserialize("json", data):
    if object_should_be_saved(deserialized_object):
        DeserializedObject.objects.update_or_create(
            id=deserialized_object.id,
            defaults={k: v for (k, v) in 
                      model_to_dict(deserialized_object).items() 
                      if k != 'id'}
        )
```